# Working with Python program in QGIS 2.18

Tags: pyqgis

I am learning Python programming and after follow the falling tutorial at http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html when typing the follow script

```
output_file = open('c:/Documents/test/airports.txt', 'w')
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    line = '%s, %s, %f, %f\n' % (f['name'], f['iata_code'],geom.asPoint().y(), geom.asPoint().x())
    unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
    output_file.write(unicode_line)
 output_file.close()
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
output_file = open('c:/Documents/test/airports.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/Documents/test/airports.txt'

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    line = '%s, %s, %f, %f\n' % (f['name'], f['iata_code'],
    geom.asPoint().y(), geom.asPoint().x())
    unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
    output_file.write(unicode_line)
output_file.close()

File "<input>", line 7
output_file.close()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to fix this?

Comment: You have a space before " output_file.close()".  Python uses indentation/whitespace as part of the syntax.  Change it to `output_file.close()`

Comment: did you create the airports.txt file before write on it ?

Answer (score 1):

> No such file or directory: 'c:/Documents/test/airports.txt'

Suggests that the path 'c:/Documents/test/' does not exist or that you do not have write permissions

> File "", line 7 output_file.close() SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Test  with an additional newline

```
output_file = open('c:/Documents/test/airports.txt', 'w')
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    line = '%s, %s, %f, %f\n' % (f['name'], f['iata_code'],geom.asPoint().y(), geom.asPoint().x())
    unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
    output_file.write(unicode_line)

output_file.close()
```